# SignalR 2.2.1 ASP.NET MVC 5 Edge/IE issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have a problem with Signal r 2.2.1 ASP.NET MVC 5. On Chrome the SignalR server works great(i can communicate with the server), but on Edge or IE he doesn't work.

The Signal R server is an ASP.NET MVC 5 Project.

Microsoft Edge Console Logging:

[image]

Chrome: [image]

Server startup code:

```
 public class StartupConfiguration : Controller
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            GlobalHost.Configuration.ConnectionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(110);
            GlobalHost.Configuration.DisconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
            // This value must be no more than 1/3 of the DisconnectTimeout value.
            GlobalHost.Configuration.KeepAlive = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);

            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
            {
                EnableDetailedErrors = true,
                EnableJSONP = false,
            };
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.MapSignalR("/signalr", hubConfiguration);
        }

    }
```

Note: Same code as Class Library (Windows Service) works great on Edge/IE/Chrome, but as Web Application (ASP.NET MVC5) it doesn't work.

Maybe I'm missing something?
Can someone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fixed by enabling the WebSocket on the server side. Microsoft Edge and IE doesn't support Server Sent Events (SSE) so the client falls back to long polling.